# How can I place a div DIRECTLY over another DIV (that contains content) with a slight offset?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a visual effect, best illustrated with this image:

[image: Text with a drop-shadow outline]

I'm accomplishing this effect with a lot of text-shadows, all of them offset in a circle.  It works.  But I want to do the same effect with a div, so that I can put the effect on images to.

I tried this:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">in a new adventure!
   <div style="position:relative;top:5;left:5;">in a new adventure!
   </div>
</div>
```

So never mind the coloring or whatnot... what I expected was the text drawn on top of the other text directly, so that it looked a little thicker.  I.E. this:

[image: expected]

But instead, I'm getting the second div UNDERNEATH the first div, with the offset there, like so:

[image]

Is there any way to position a div with content directly 100% over another div with content?  My intention is to offset the bottom z-order div in order to make a bottom-heavy stroke like in the top image.

Comment: position:absolute maybe?

Comment: It makes it absolute to the first div's container, whatever it is, when I do that.  I can't see to get two things directly overlapping each other, I keep getting html avoidance effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[TBN!] Run the snippet in full screen to see the effect (it's not responsive :p)***

- you need three elements to add the effect one behind the text and one under the text to add dimension and I used `-webkit-text-stroke` to add the padding, and using  word-spacing and letter-spacing I control the text

```css
#outer {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #3993cc;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 900;
    word-spacing: -17px;
    font-family: arial;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 14px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #3993cc;
}

#outer2 {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #3993cc;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 900;
    word-spacing: -17px;
    top : 10px;
    left : 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 11px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #3993cc;
}

#inner {
     color: white;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 4.4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 3px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;

}

body {
  background: #a3efff;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
in a new adventure!
  <div id="outer2">
in a new adventure!

</div>
  <span id="inner">
  in a new adventure!
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: One thing about this though... if your text is not to the far right of its container, it breaks.  Putting <center> in front will center the #outer div but the other two will be far left.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">in a new adventure!
   <div style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:1px;">in a new adventure!
   </div>
</div>
```

By the way, don't forget to add the unit after your value.

Or you can use negative margins:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">in a new adventure!
   <div style="position:relative;margin-top: -20px;">in a new adventure!
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That ends up making it absolute to whatever the first div is inside.  I.E. if it's just on the page, it becomes absolute to the page upper left, if it's in a table, it becomes absolute to the table's upper left.

Comment: Use negative margins?

Comment: @JohnRaptis thats why you use a wrapper with `position: relative`. That way you can place the wrapper where ever you want and the `positon: absolute` as childs will only adjust to the wrapper not the other element you talk about.