# Real outline for text

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, outline

Is it possible to easily outline text with html/css? I don't mean putting a shadow behind it with text-shadow property but outlining the text with strokes.

Comment: check this it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508701/how-can-i-place-a-div-directly-over-another-div-that-contains-content-with-a-s/64508943#64508943

Comment: It seems a lot of people have tried adding an outline to text, This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text) has a lot of different approaches. For what it's worth, pure css outlines are well supported on modern browsers, if you have no need for SVG, I would stick to a css solution.

Comment: @Lars ah, I used that topic as an inspiration since there wasn't a really satisfying information, but I guess that Ï'll just go with the text-shadow...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.stroke {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px limegreen;
  color: transparent;
}

.stroke-explicit {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;
  color: transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="stroke">Shorthand</h1>
<h1 class="stroke-explicit">Both properties</h1>
```